# How to find the number of characters that a UILabel can Hold?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to find the number of characters that a `UILabel` can hold. I am using

```
lbl_Text = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,15,290,320)];
lbl_Text.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lbl_Text.numberOfLines = 20;
lbl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
```

to set the `font` and `font size`.
Can anyone find the number of characters that this `UILabel` can hold ?

Comment: Remember, "wwwwwwwwww" is wider than "iiiiiiiiii" but they have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size of a particular string in a particular font with NSString's `sizeWithFont:` method. You can't ask "how many characters can I fit?" because in a proportional spaced font like Helvetica all the characters occupy different widths. Typically you know exactly what you need to display but size can vary, so you can check sizes with successively smaller fonts until you find the size that fits (which is why some of the native controls will automatically do this for you).